# symfony2 crud user entity, role assign

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm having trouble with crud and user entity ( playing a little with sf2). i've been following the symfony cookbook for saving users in database and roles and i've generated crud for user entity and role entity. on user entity i have the field for assigning the role yet in the select option it shows the id of the role instead of the name and i'm not sure how modify the field to show the role name. can you help me please ?

**User Controller:**

```
namespace UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use UserBundle\Entity\User;
use UserBundle\Form\UserType;

/**
 * User controller.
 *
 * @Route("/user")
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all User entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="user")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entities = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->findAll();

        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="user_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("UserBundle:User:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new User();
        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($entity);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($entity->getPassword(), $entity->getSalt());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a User entity.
     *
     * @param User $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(User $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="user_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new User();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="user_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a User entity.
    *
    * @param User $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(User $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("UserBundle:User:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find User entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('user'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a User entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('user_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

**UserType**

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('isActive')
            ->add('roles')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'userbundle_user';
    }
}
```

**UserEntity**

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="acme_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     */
    private $roles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid(null, true));
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::serialize()
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @see \Serializable::unserialize()
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }

    /**
     * Add roles
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRole(\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles[] = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove roles
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles
     */
    public function removeRole(\UserBundle\Entity\Role $roles)
    {
        $this->roles->removeElement($roles);
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->getId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `__toString()` method in the `Role` entity class.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

You could also pass `'property' => 'name'` option to `roles` field

Read more about other form type options here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Comment: my method was $this->id instead of name :-) cheers mate thank you for your help i dunno why i didn't think of this :D